# .Where(Date.AddHours) filter doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#

I'm sorting a list of files that was created from yesterday 1:00pm to present time. I'm trying to use the following code: The messagebox shows the correct time I'm trying to reference, but the filter doesn't seem to work. If I remove the "AddHours(13)" it does filter correctly.

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(13).ToString());
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.xls")
    .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date >= (DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(13)) && file.Contains("AA"))
    .OrderBy(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date)
    .ToArray();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So what does `new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date` show?

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(13)` will return 1pm... but you're checking against `new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date`, which is always at midnight... for a file created yesterday, it will be yesterday at midnight.

So yes, you're filtering out that file. If you remove the `.Date` part from `new FileInfo(file).CreationTime` that may well be all you need to do.

As a side-note, I'd use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`, and I'd also try to avoid evaluating it multiple times. I'd also use `DirectoryInfo` and stick to `FileInfo` entries given that you're already creating those twoce. I'd rewrite your query as something like:

```
var cutoff = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(13);
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath).GetFiles("*.xls")
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime >= cutoff)
    .OrderBy(file => file.CreationTime)
    .ToArray();
```